# I get an SQL syntax error when using this query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

this works:

```
 string sqlStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO tblFiles (filename,downloadname,description,category,length,parts,checksum,isEncrypted,uploaderIp) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},{5},'{6}',{7},'{8}');",
            newFile.Name.Replace("'", "''"), newFile.DownloadName.Replace("'", "''"), newFile.Description, newFile.Category, newFile.Length, newFile.Parts, newFile.Checksum, newFile.IsEncrypted, GetPeerIp());
```

this doesn't:

```
string sqlStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO tblFiles (filename,downloadname,description,category,length,parts,checksum,isEncrypted,password,uploaderIp) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},{5},'{6}',{7},'{8}','{9}');",
        newFile.Name.Replace("'", "''"), newFile.DownloadName.Replace("'", "''"), newFile.Description, newFile.Category, newFile.Length, newFile.Parts, newFile.Checksum, newFile.IsEncrypted, password, GetPeerIp());
```

Exception I get:

> $exception {"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."}  System.Exception {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException}

my database looks like this.

[image]

I couldn't find any problem with it. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: As a general rule, always use command parameters to avoid malicious sql injection and other unexpected errors. You can save some coding for simple (validated) integers but never for user provided data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Password is a reserved keyword in MS-Access sql. If you have a field with that name you need to encapsulate that name between square brackets (better change it now)

```
string sqlStr = @"INSERT INTO tblFiles 
   (filename,downloadname,description,category,length,parts,
   checksum,isEncrypted,[password],uploaderIp) VALUES (.....)";
```

Said that, please, remove all that string concatenations and use a parameterized query. Not only this is more safe (prevents Sql Injections) but also removes all the problems with quoting and correct parsing of dates and decimal numbers

```
string sqlStr = @"INSERT INTO tblFiles 
   (filename,downloadname,description,category,length,parts,
   checksum,isEncrypted,[password],uploaderIp) VALUES 
   (@file, @down, @desc, @cat, @len, @parts, @check, @enc, @pass, @up)";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlStr, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@file", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = newFile.Name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@down", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = newFile.DownloadName;
... and so on for all other parameters respecting the OleDbType of the column....

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice how your query is more clear and understandable and how you don't need to call a lot of Replace just to get rid of possible embedded single quotes.